# Is it possible to remove "Tap for Preview" with sending Twilio SMS Messages to iOS 10 iMessage

Tags: iphone, twilio, ios10

We have recently implemented Open Graph Protocol in our site, and when we send SMS messages via Twilio with a link to our iOS 10 users, then see the customary "Tap to preview".  Once the users taps the link, the image displays with title listed beneath.

We have noted some websites such as Pitchfork.com send out SMS messages and these skip the "Tap to Preview" step I listed above.  In other words, the Open Graph Image is displayed without clicking.

To isolate our issue, tested by sending out SMS with just the link to our site, but we still received the "Tap To Preview".   This conforms with the Apple rules of including the link at the very beginning or end of the message.

Is there formatting that we are not aware of that we need to do in order to produce the behavior like the PitchFork site?

Comment: +1 to this. I have no solution but I am having the same issue. Have tried multiple ways and am scratching my head, out of ideas.

Here's some other things I tried so far this **DID NOT WORK**

- Switch from jpg/png and serve static image.
- reduced preview o 50x50 (testing that maybe the image is too large, either in size or in dimensions (for automatic)
- Stripped page of all other HTML tags except for the OG tags, in case scripts or other page contents are causing the preview to not load.
- Removed any intermediate redirects.

No luck.

Comment: It could be. Someone in marketing receives via a service.  With have to follow up with her.  Thx for the tip